# Android 6.0 getLastKnowLocationPermission

Tags: android, permissions, geo

I have a error when I'm trying to get last known location in Android 6.0

```
Location lastLocation =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.SecurityException: "network" location provider requires
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

**My manifest:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

**check permissions:**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            try {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                        1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        PointDTO point = new PointDTO();

        try {
            Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
//            //        String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
//            //        String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
//            address= addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            point.setLat(lastLocation.getLatitude());
            point.setLon(lastLocation.getLongitude());

        } catch (NullPointerException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return point;
```

What I did wrong? It works in Android Api 23-

**UPD:**

*NPE:*

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                    1);
```

*SecurityException*

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: please check whether you are getting exception

Comment: I think you can't even get the last known location without the user grant you access to the locations

Comment: @MohammadAbbas I'm trying to get it with request permissions, and manifest has this permission.  How then do in this case?

Comment: This is because you are doing location getting work without permission work successful execution, please check answer given by readyandroid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do get location work if runtime location permissions are given for marshmallow(android api 23 or above), check this:

This line of code

```
Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

here will show you error in code for security exception and ask to use runtime permission code everywhere for code, no need to worry you can execute the build with this error info.

```
private void checkRuntimePermissions(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            try {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                        1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            getMyLocation();
        }
    }

    private PointDTO getMyLocation(){
        PointDTO point = new PointDTO();
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
//            //        String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
//            //        String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
//            address= addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            point.setLat(lastLocation.getLatitude());
            point.setLon(lastLocation.getLongitude());

        } catch (NullPointerException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return point;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
            case REQ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! 
                    checkRuntimePermissions();
                } else {
                    //do other operation because permission not given
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I alos had the same problem while doing these.You should access location after granting the permission

it should be inside method `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

refer request permission [blog](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
I will try it and  inform you of the results

Comment: please try i will wait